# OpenGL camera control with arrow keys

Tags: opengl, camera, trigonometry, angle

Right now, I got my camera working for moving forward and backwards.

I have a routine for my arrow keys that change the values of my camera variable which is used in the gluLookAt call.

```
gluLookAt(camera.ex,camera.ey, camera.ez,
    camera.cx,camera.cy,camera.cz,
    camera.x,camera.y,camera.z);


// Callback routine for non-ASCII key entry.
void specialKeyInput(int key, int x, int y)
{

if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) camera.ez -= 0.1;
if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) camera.ez += 0.1;
if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) camera.cx -= 0.1;
if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) camera.cx += 0.1;

glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The issue I'm facing with by doing this, is that even if I'm facing (say to the left), and I press the up key, I"m offsetting my camera.ez value instead of the correct camera.ex value. So my question is, how do you handle camera movements in OpenGL? Do I have to keep track of the "angle" I'm looking at, and do some trig?

Comment: You trying to do [something like this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31042)?

Comment: @genpfault yes I believe so. Although I'm not entirely sure how to follow that...

Answer (score 3):

You should keep track of camera orientation to move your camera in correct coordinate system, i.e. local to the camera(model space). Also, to avoid [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), you should start using quaternions.
The reason to use quaternions is when you are dealing with Euler angles it's important to follow correct [rotation order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Relationship_with_physical_motions) otherwise you wont get what you want.

Here is simple example of quaternion-based first-person camera class using glm library:

```
class Camera
{
public:
    void move(glm::vec3 directions, glm::vec2 rotations, float frametime);
    // ... constructors etc.
private:
    glm::mat4 view_;
    glm::vec3 camera_pos_;
    glm::quat camera_orientation_;
    const float camera_speed_;
}

// move directions - (forward/backward/0, left/right/0, up/down/0). each direction could be 1, -1 or 0
// rotations - (horizontal_amount, vertical_amount)
void Camera::move(glm::vec3 directions, glm::vec2 rotations, float frametime)
{
    auto pitch = glm::quat(glm::vec3(-rotations.y, 0, 0.f));
    auto yaw = glm::quat(glm::vec3(0, -rotations.x, 0.f));

    camera_orientation_ = glm::normalize(yaw * camera_orientation_ * pitch);

    auto camera_roll_direction = camera_orientation_ * glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
    auto camera_pitch_direction = camera_orientation_ * glm::vec3(-1, 0, 0);

    // forward/backward move - all axes could be affected
    camera_pos_ += directions[0] * camera_roll_direction * frametime * camera_speed_;
    // left and right strafe - only xz could be affected    
    camera_pos_ += directions[1] * camera_pitch_direction * frametime * camera_speed_;
    // up and down flying - only y-axis could be affected
    camera_pos_.y += directions[2] * frametime * camera_speed_;

    view_ = glm::lookAt(camera_pos_, camera_pos_ + camera_roll_direction,
                        glm::cross(camera_roll_direction, camera_pitch_direction));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
main_loop()
{
    //...
    glm::vec2 rotation;
    glm::vec3 directions;
    rotation.x = get_mouse_move_x_offset();
    rotation.y = get_mouse_move_y_offset();

    if(is_key_pressed(KEY_D)) directions.y = -1;
    if(is_key_pressed(KEY_A)) directions.y = 1;
    if(is_key_pressed(KEY_W)) directions.x = 1;
    if(is_key_pressed(KEY_S)) directions.x = -1;
    if(is_key_pressed(KEY_E)) directions.z = 1; 
    if(is_key_pressed(KEY_Q)) directions.z = -1;

    cam.move(directions, rotation, frametime); 
}
```

The order of `yaw * camera_orientation_ * pitch` multiplication is important because we need to apply yaw transformation in world-space and pitch transformation in model-space.

For more information about quaternions and rotations consider reading [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/) tutorial.

Comment: Is it possible to not use any external libraries and to keep it "pure" as possible? I know this sounds like a silly requirement.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat you can implement quaternion and matrix classes relatively easy yourself, but I don't see any point of doing it, as long as you are not trying to achieve best performance possible. Also GLM is a header-only cross-platform library so you wont need any library files, just #include required headers

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat Also you'll need to implement vectors and vector operations. glm::lookat just returns matrix that you'll need to pass to the vertex shader(if you are using opengl 3+). If you are using opengl 2.0 you can set your modelview matrix using glMatrixMode and glLoadMatrix functions. If you are not familiar with matrix transformations I strongly recommend you to learn about [them](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).